# Serving Image Assets From a CDN in a Simple Rails Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline, cdn

I have a feeling this is a simple question that I'm just missing something, but I've thought about it and Googled a bit and haven't come up with anything yet.

I am running a Rails app on Heroku, using the asset pipeline, and serving static assets through a CDN using asset_sync. However, for my super simple blog I realized that it's serving assets through the app itself because I simply call in my view:

```
<%= @blog.body %>
```

The blog model is title (string), body (text), description (string). And the body is just a text blob of html. So for an image I'd include a line like the following as part of @blog.body:

```
<img alt="Clever alt tag" src="/assets/blog/my_image.jpg">
```

Is there a way to use this simple approach but have the image assets served from the CDN instead of the Heroku app?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write your blog post using something like [ckeditor](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails), which can play nicely with the asset pipeline.